# How to install Python2.7 additional libraries

Tags: python-2.7, installation, setup.py

http://code.google.com/p/rdfextras/

I need to download the above library and install it. I wonder whether the way that I'm gonna do it is correct or not.

First of all, I'll download the file to the following folder.

C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages

And then in the command prompt,
[image]

Is that the correct way to install it ? Or else, is there another way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

`site-packages` are where modules get installed. Don't download anything there unless you want to potentially damage your Python installation. Download it somewhere else and then install it.

Comment: you mean to say that first of all I should download it and then save it somewhere else...ryt ? anyways, I'll have to copy and paste it to the site-packages folder...ryt ? Can you pls explain it little bit further ?

Comment: I mean exactly what I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pip. It can install other libraries from the pypi and it can also install for tar packahe.Google it out

Comment: Please use a virtualenviorment. it will dont mess with your python installment.

Comment: Please use a virtualenviorment. it will don't mess with your python Installation. 
step 1: mkvirtualenv env_name
step 2: source env_name/Scripts/activate (activating the env)
step 3: pip install mypackage --no-index --find-links file:///srv/pkg/mypackage